# How can I select multiple values from a dropdown list in Google Sheets?

Tags: formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have created a drop-down list, and I want to select multiple values every time I click on it. Is there a way to do without the script editor?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RzSV_JkMlHOxA46L4AsGr-8JbnfcH2fc-QQdvzW9wOA/edit#gid=1612644763

Comment: I am afraid you can not. You will have to create all possible combinations. I looked at your sheet. What values would you wish to select?

Comment: Something similar to this type of function - https://spreadsheetpoint.com/multiple-selection-drop-down-google-sheets/

Comment: Only with a script (which actually is a hack). But why would you want that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am planning on using that as an indicator to alert teachers of potential problems with the student. The number of values selected will count as an offense. After enough of them are selected, it will send out an email to the administrator.

Comment: So you will have 1st offense, 2nd offense and so on. Then why should one pick multiple values? I am trying to understand the logic behind it.

Comment: Sometimes, a student can possibly commit multiple offenses, such as not bring in the required materials and coming to class late.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119150/discussion-between-marikamitsos-and-vineyard-teacher).