# How to add multiple pre-created values to the same cell in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

With google sheets if you add data validation, you can select a single value from a predefined list of values (or from another specified range of values). This makes data entry a lot faster and more precise.

However I would like to do the same but without being constrained to a *single* value. So suppose I got this list of values

```
healthy
cheap
expensive
trendy
mexican
fast food
```

And I would like the ability to quickly select from the above list _multiple values to the same cell, so that it can end up having for example:
`expensive, mexican`

Comment: Hi. Have you read [How can I select multiple values from a dropdown list in Google Sheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/150559/196152)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a script that runs on a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), like this:

```
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user hand edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error('Please do not run the script in the script editor window. '
      + 'It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet.');
  }
  multiSelectDropDownList_(e);
}


/**
* Enables clumsy but workable multi-select drop-down lists.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function multiSelectDropDownList_(e) {
  // version 1.4, written by --Hyde, 22 January 2024
  //  - add rowStart, rowEnd
  if (e.value === undefined || e.oldValue === undefined) return;
  try {
    const parameters = [

      ////////////////////////////////
      // [START modifiable parameters]
      {
        sheetsToWatch: /^(Sheet1)$/i,
        columnsToWatch: [4, 5,],
        rowStart: 1,
        rowEnd: +Infinity,
        separator: ', ',
      },
      {
        sheetsToWatch: /^(Sheet2|Sheet3)$/i,
        columnsToWatch: [5, 6,],
        rowStart: 20,
        rowEnd: 30,
        separator: ', ',
      },
      {
        sheetsToWatch: /./i, // matches all sheets
        columnsToWatch: [26,],
        rowStart: 1,
        rowEnd: 2,
        separator: ' - ',
      },
      // [END modifiable parameters]
      ////////////////////////////////

    ];
    let sheet;
    const settings = parameters.filter(par =>
      par.columnsToWatch.includes(e.range.columnStart)
      && par.rowStart <= e.range.rowStart
      && par.rowEnd >= e.range.rowEnd
      && (sheet = sheet || e.range.getSheet()).getName().match(par.sheetsToWatch)
    )[0];
    if (!settings) return;
    let newValue = e.oldValue;
    if (e.oldValue !== e.value
      && !e.oldValue.startsWith(e.value + settings.separator)
      && !e.oldValue.endsWith(settings.separator + e.value)
      && !e.oldValue.includes(settings.separator + e.value + settings.separator)) {
      newValue += settings.separator + e.value;
    }
    const rule = e.range.getDataValidation();
    if (rule && !rule.getAllowInvalid()) {
      e.range.setDataValidation(rule.copy().setAllowInvalid(true).build());
    }
    e.range.setValue(newValue);
  } catch (error) {
    e.source.toast(`${error.message} ${error.stack}`, 'Error in multiSelectDropDownList_()', 30)
  }
}
```

To install the script, paste the code in **Tools > Script editor**, completely replacing the `myFunction()` placeholder there. Configure it to the column where you have the drop-down lists by modifying the parameters.

Comment: The function as shown will do its thing in any cell in column `5`, i.e., column `E` in the sheets `Sheet1`, `Sheet2` and `Sheet3`. Edit the code to set another column and a different set of sheets as necessary.