# Have multiple selections in drop down Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to make it so that I can select two types of membership for one individual (e.g. volunteer and family). [image]

Answer (score 2):

There are scripted solutions such as [multiSelectDropDownList_](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/159321/269219) that let you choose more than one value in a dropdown. The values typically get joined together with a comma separator. There are downsides, such as these cells showing a red triangle in the corner and an error message when you hover over them.

It would probably more make sense to insert as many columns as you have membership types and **Insert > Checkbox** in those columns to let you choose any combination of membership types for each individual.

Answer (score -2):

### A `QUERY` with `Matches` formula suggestion:

```
=ArrayFormula(
IFNA(
    QUERY(A3:C9, "SELECT * WHERE LOWER(B) MATCHES LOWER('"&E1&"') AND LOWER(C) CONTAINS LOWER('"&E2&"')", 0),
    "No Matches Found.")
    )
```

### Input and Output:

`E1` accepts the regular expression "`Fruit|Vegetable`" matching the corresponding input rows values from range `A3:C9`, and returns the corresponding filtered values in range `A12:C15`.

[image: Input and Output]

### DEMO:

[image: DEMO]

### Sample:

| Title1 | Title2 | Title3 | Title4 | Title5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  | Fruit |
|  |  |  |  | comestible |
| Banana | Fruit | comestible |  |  |
| Cucumber | Vegetable | comestible |  |  |
| Cherry | Fruit | comestible |  |  |
| Cod | Fish | comestible |  |  |
| Mercury | Metal | inedible |  |  |
| Spinach | Vegetable | comestible |  |  |
| Onyx | Mineral | inedible |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| Banana | Fruit | comestible |  |  |
| Cucumber | Vegetable | comestible |  |  |
| Cherry | Fruit | comestible |  |  |
| Spinach | Vegetable | comestible |  |  |

### Sources and references:

[Matches Regular Expression Match in Google Sheets Query](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/matches-regular-expression-match-in-google-sheets-query/)

[How to Use Cell Reference in Google Sheets Query](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/cell-reference-in-google-sheets-query/)

### Helpful Preliminary Query Formula Concepts:

[Google Sheets Query Formula with Dropdown List (Data Validation) Cell Reference - Dynamic Dashboard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPz2MPQInOM)

[QUERY - Drop Down List to Filter Data - Google Sheets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLW8SerwnJo)

### Script Alternatives:

[Google Sheets Tutorial – How to Enable Multiple Selection Data Validation Using Apps Script](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/google-sheets-multiple-data-validation-selections/)

[How to Make Multiple Selection in Drop-down Lists in Google Sheets](https://spreadsheetpoint.com/multiple-selection-drop-down-google-sheets/)

[How to Make Multiple Selection in Dropdown in Google Sheets](https://sheetsformarketers.com/how-to-make-multiple-selection-in-dropdown-in-google-sheets/)